# Handling web page dialogues with WATIN

Tags: watin, dialog

I have a web page that pops up a web page dialog. How can i handle this using WatiN ?

Answer (score 0):

If your popup is really a new browser window, to access it you'll need to create a new WatiN IE object tp attach to your popup.

You can attach to the popup using the name of the popup or the URL. If you use WatiN 1.3 it will look like this :

By page name:

```
IE ie = IE.AttachToIE(Find.ByTitle("MyPageName"));
```

By url:

```
IE ie = IE.AttachToIE(Find.ByUrl("http://www.test.com/popup.htm"));
```

It's should work with WatiN 2.0 RC1, but they add other mechanism to do it, check here : http://watinandmore.blogspot.com/2010/01/browserattachto-and-iattachto.html